# codeigniter: how to put the value of the array into a specific table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, insert

I have an array like this

```
array(12) {
            [0]=> string(1) "3"
            [1]=> string(1) "3"
            [2]=> string(1) "5"
            [3]=> string(1) "3"
            [4]=> string(1) "4"
            [5]=> string(1) "3"
            [6]=> string(1) "3"
            [7]=> string(1) "3"
            [8]=> string(1) "2"
            [9]=> string(1) "3"
            [10]=> string(1) "2"
            [11]=> string(1) "3" 
        }
```

the array is dynamic, so, array value can be changed anytime

I also have a mysql table with a structure like this

```
|id|bobot_c1|bobot_c2|bobot_c3|bobot_c4|bobot_c5|bobot_c6|bobot_c7|bobot_c8|bobot_c9|bobot_c10|bobot_c11|bobot_c12|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |         |         |         | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**id** is **auto_increment**

how do I enter the key array: `"3", "3", "5", "3"` and others into the database table?

so for the value **index [0]**, I enter into **bobot_c1** column, **index [1]**, into **bobot_c2** column and others.

thank you!

Comment: `for($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++)   $data['robot_c'.$i] = $array[$i]; $this->db->insert("table_name",  $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an another array like this:

```
$dataArray = (
       'bobot_c1' => $array[0],
       'bobot_c2' => $array[1],
       'bobot_c3' => $array[2],
       'bobot_c4' => $array[3],
        .
        .
        .
       );
```

similarly add more columns and insert $dataArray into database.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you already know the basics of codeigniter on how to pass data
from controllers to models

Here is user guide of [CodeIgniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

```
// construct an array with indexes like this
// the indexes pertains to the table columns 
// and the value will be the indexes value
$data = array(
    "bobot_c1" => "3",
    "bobot_c2" => "3",
    "bobot_c3" => "5",
    "bobot_c4" => "3",
    "bobot_c5" => "4",
    "bobot_c6" => "3",
    "bobot_c7" => "3",
    "bobot_c8" => "3",
    "bobot_c9" => "2",
    "bobot_c10" => "3",
    "bobot_c11" => "2",
    "bobot_c12" => "3"
);

// table name you want to insert data

$table = "table_name"

// use codeigniter active record to
// insert data
$this->db->insert($table,  $data);
```

Comment: oh my mistake, the array is dynamic so any time the value of the array can be changed @OliSoproniB.

Comment: @BayuAnggaSatrio if the array is dynamic you need still to come up with a   process to create an array structure same like with your table columns like  my $data array. Hope you get what i mean

Answer (score 1):

construct the sql like this:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table (columns here) " .
            "VALUES (".implode($array,",").")";
  $this->db->query($sql);// no need to add id column in sql since it is auto increatented value
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

- Your ***bobot_ columns*** type should be *double* or *int* or *else number*.

**Second**

- Because your data is **string** you should parse the **string data** to **number** when **inserting**

---

**And this is the Query**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, bobot_c1, bobot_c2, bobot_c3, bobot_c4, bobot_c5, bobot_c6, bobot_c7, bobot_c8, bobot_c9, bobot_c10, bobot_c11, bobot_c12)
VALUES (NULL, CONVERT(INT, $index[0]), CONVERT(INT, $index[1]), CONVERT(INT, $index[2]), CONVERT(INT, $index[3]), CONVERT(INT, $index[4]), CONVERT(INT, $index[5]), CONVERT(INT, $index[6]), CONVERT(INT, $index[7]), CONVERT(INT, $index[8]), CONVERT(INT, $index[9]), CONVERT(INT, $index[10]), CONVERT(INT, $index[11]));
```

---

**This is tutorial to convert that query for *CodeIgniter***

```
/*
    class Myclass {
        var $title = 'My Title';
        var $content = 'My Content';
        var $date = 'My Date';
    }
*/

$object = new Myclass;

$this->db->insert('mytable', $object); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, content, date) VALUES ('My Title', 'My Content', 'My Date')
```

Comment: data type on my table column is varchar, do I need to change it? @JosuaMarcelChrisano

Comment: no need its ok but the type can be null right? if the bobot data can be null its ok to $this->db->insert('table', $yourArray); on your model

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$cols = 11;
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ( ";

  for($i=0; $i<$cols; $i++){
      if($i!=0)
          $sql .=", bobot_c" . ($i+1);
      else
          $sql .="bobot_c" . ($i+1);
  }

$sql .=" ) VALUES( ";

for($i=0; $i<$cols; $i++){
    if($i!=0)
        $sql .=", '" .$array[$i] . "'";
    else
        $sql .="'" .$array[$i] . "'";
}
$sql .=" )";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```